# What are the differences that a doctype make in a html page?

Tags: html, doctype

What is the difference between having a page doctype or not having one, apart from the fact that the page should have one ?

I am asking that because I use a slider inside this page - with the doctype, the slider has a wrong high (150px), and without it, it has the desired high (with the correct ratio high/width from the iframes which are in the slider).

I have tried with multiple doctypes, with the same result for each of them.

Comment: please consider commenting before downvoting, otherwise it doesn't help me understand what information are missing

Comment: There are many, many differences, but a good place to start is with the [Quirks Mode Standard](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: With the doctype it won't have a wrong height. It will have the proper height, but probably you misunderstood how the box model is designed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a `doctype` to state what flavour of `html` you are using, the browser will revert to *quirks mode*, where it tries to parse your markup as if it were a legacy document from before the year 2000.

Nothing about this is optimal. You have an invalid hypertext document and the browser will render the document as it might have been rendered prior to the adoption of W3C standards at the end of the last century.

> In quirks mode, layout emulates nonstandard behavior in Navigator 4
>   and Internet Explorer 5. This is essential in order to support
>   websites that were built before the widespread adoption of web
>   standards.

**Source:** http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

In short, you need a `doctype` at the start of **every** hypertext document.

---

For a **Complete List of HTML and xHTML Doctype Declarations**, see:

https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: That's incorrect. As far as *parsing* an HTML document goes, absence of a doctype makes only one difference - a start `<table>` tag encountered when a `<p>` element is open will close the p element when a standards mode giving doctype is present and not if a doctype is absent.